# Methods to disable colleague suggestions

Tags: user-profile, email

I have a couple test farms that I use and recently it sent out the monthly colleague suggestion email to all of my users who had profiles in the test domain.

I've found several articles in research that cover a range of fixes...but i'm not sure which one will do the job.

The obvious easy one would be the timer job "User Profile Service – My Site Suggestions Email Job" but i've read that this still sends out the emails even if it is disabled? Is this really true?? Since i would have to disable and wait a month before i can see if it tested out true or false i wanted to ask.

The other route i've seen is to run a script that disables the configuration within each users profile site (there are 3) but you have to follow up with any new users added and this could be annoying to have to keep maintaining that on a test farm.

http://sharepointjotter.blogspot.com/2012/01/worried-that-lots-of-emails-will-be.html

The third route i've read about involves configuring the GPO on the client boxes...but this is out of the question as they would not recieve any emails from any of the farms i have production or test.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepoint2010setup/thread/291ee2a6-d3b1-4e86-9afd-bf24a66ddb60

I'd like to think this problem is as easy as turning off the timer job...does anyone else know for sure? what do you do in your test farms to control this, other than removing outbound email settings :)